# jenkins ssh pipeline plugin does not hangup with docker run

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the ssh pipeline plugin to ssh into my docker host, pull and run an image

```
stage("Remote SSH 2") {
.
.
.
                writeFile file: 'run.sh', text: 'docker run --name blahxyz:latest && exit;'
                sshScript remote: remote, script: "run.sh"
                sshRemove remote: remote, path: "run.sh"
.
.
.
            }
```

This bit is the bit I need help on. After it runs it never moves on as the container on command line does that as its running npm start and thus will not exit. How do I run it and exit the ssh so I can move on? Ive tried to add & and now && exit but I just hang up

Comment: could you clarify? I am not able to understand what you really want.

Comment: so if you run docker run from ssh it does not end ie keeps running and so it will not move onto the next step in my pipeline. I need to ssh in do the docker run and exit leaving the container running

Comment: can't you run the container in detached mode? `docker run -d <image>`

Comment: thank you i forgot about -d!! that works